# Move Constructor invoked for a function, but NRVO expected in C++

Tags: c++, return-value, move-semantics, rvalue-reference, rvalue

I don't understand why a move constructor is being invoked during the main function in the code below, specifically the output is:

```
FString::FString(string one)
FString::FString(string two)
FString::Move Constructor
FString::Move Assign
COMPLETE
```

So the line I am concerned about is "FString::Move Constructor" - this implies to me that the move constructor is getting invoked in order to fulfill the return statement of the function GetStringTemp(), but from what I understood NRVO should mean that the move constructor should not be invoked. Am I misunderstanding the behaviour of NVRO? Thanks in advance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class FString
{
    public:
        FString(std::string newstring)
        : _string(newstring)
        {
            std::cout << "FString::FString(string "+newstring+")" << std::endl;
        }

        FString(const FString& rhs) 
        {
            std::cout << "FString::Copy Constructor" << std::endl;
        }

        FString(FString&& rhs) 
        {
            std::cout << "FString::Move Constructor" << std::endl;
        }

        FString& operator=(const FString& rhs)
        {
            std::cout << "FString::Copy Assign" << std::endl;
            return *this;
        }

        FString& operator=(FString&& rhs)
        {
            std::cout << "FString::Move Assign" << std::endl;
            return *this;
        }

        void Print()
        {
            std::cout << "Printing: "+_string << std::endl;
        }

    private:
        std::string _string;
};

FString GetTempString()
{
    FString temp = FString("two"); // 2: Expected Constructor cout
    return temp; // No expected constructor as NVRO assumed
}

int main()
{
    FString myString = FString("one"); // 1: Expected Constructor cout
    myString = GetTempString(); // 3: Expected Move Assignment cout

    std::cout << "COMPLETE" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: NRVO is not guaranteed. It is optional, but not required.

Comment: NRVO is not mandatory. What are you compiling with? gcc, and clang [don't](https://godbolt.org/z/YAkTVR) move construct.

Comment: As far as I know, only RVO (not NRVO) is required by C++17 standard.

Comment: Aha, yeah I'm compiling with the Microsoft cl compiler, so it's probably explained by the fact that RVO is not actually required!

Comment: @MattNewcombe "_so it's probably explained by the fact that RVO is not actually required!_" Don't confuse RVO, and NRVO. Starting with C++17 (are you compiling with it enabled, since MSVS default to C++14) only RVO, and **not NRVO**, is required.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, yeah I'm compiling with 14

Comment: What matters is not only the compiler version, but also what optimisations you are compiling with. What are those?